# An interesting recurrent equality, possibly easier to solve in its differential form?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, inequality, recurrence-relations, recursion

> I encountered an interesting inequality that I'm not sure how to approach. Here $c$ is a positive constant.
> $$f(n+1) - f(n) = c f(n)\sum_{m=0}^n f(m)$$

I am not familiar with techniques to solve recursive equations, so I thought about a similar differential equation of it $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = cf(x)\int_{z=0}^x f(z)dz.$$

I am quite new to the topic of differential equations though, so I might be missing some obvious techniques to solve this kind of equality. With my limited knowledge I tried applying Laplace transform or the Fourier transform to this equation to no avail, but the expression looks nice enough that I suspect there is an analytical solution to it. Any help to getting an analytical expression of this equation is much appreciated!

(This is coming from a real-world problem, so for now, any "nice" assumption on $f$ and the initial conditions and so on can be placed)

Comment: An inequality does not define a sequence, so you can't "*solve*" it.

Comment: @dxiv Do you mean I am missing initial conditions? Or assumptions on $f$? This is coming from an engineering problem so any nice assumption on $f$ to make the math go through is fine.

Comment: What I meant is that the inequality does not define the sequence univocally, so it is pointless to try to "*solve*" it. Take for example a trivial inequality $\,f_{n+1} - f_n \ge 1\,$, then either of $\,f_n = n\,$, $\,f_n = n^2\,$ or $\,f_n = 2^n\,$ satisfies it. There is no unique solution, so you can't "*solve*" it.

Comment: @dxiv Ok, but I'm only interested in the expression of $f_n$ that grows the slowest, is that impossible to obtain in the current context?

Comment: Replace the $\,\ge\,$ with an $\,=\,$, if that's what you meant to ask. Then the question becomes a legitimate one, though it's unilkely that a closed form solution exists.

Comment: @dxiv Alright, thank you for the pointers. Let me just write the equality then.

Comment: Is the question about the recurrence sequence, or about the differential equation? There are some ways the functions would be similar, but they won't be the same thing.

Comment: @aschepler I think within the real-world setting, it is safe to consider the differential equation for now (if that makes things simpler).

Comment: It makes things _different_, and maybe just too different (though then again, maybe not). For example, the solution to the differential equation goes to infinity at some finite $x$. The recurrence sequence does no such thing.

Comment: When I take the derivative of the second equation I get $(f'')f -c(f^3) = (f')^2$  which looks pretty difficult.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question comes in two variants. One is discrete.
The other continuous.

The discrete variant asks about the equation
$$ f(n+1) - f(n) = c f(n)\sum_{m=0}^n f(m). \tag{1} $$
A nicer version of this is to define
$$ a_n := c f(n), \qquad b_n := 1 + \sum_{m=0}^n a_m. \tag{2} $$
Multiply equation $(1)$ by $\,c\,$ to get
$$ a_{n+1} = a_n + a_n\sum_{m=0}^n a_m = a_n b_n
= a_0\prod_{m=0}^n b_m \tag{3} $$
where the initial value $\,a_0\,$ is arbitrary. A
simple example is if $\,a_0=1.\,$ This is
[OEIS sequence A001697](https://oeis.org/A001697).
The growth rate is given as $\,a_n \sim c^{2^n}\,$
where $\,c \approx 1.335245.\,$ This is the typical
growth rate with a different constant for each
choice of  $\,a_0.\,$ I don't think there is a
known closed form.

---

The continuous variant asks about the related differential equation
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = cf(x)\int_{z=0}^x f(z)dz. \tag{4} $$
This is more interesting. The equation is equivalent to
$$ \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} = c\int_{z=0}^x e^{g(z)}dz \;\;
\text{ where } \;\; g(x) := \log(f(x)).  $$
Assuming $\,g(x)\,$ has a power series, let
$$ g(x) = a_0 + a_2\frac{x^2}{2!} + a_4\frac{x^4}{4!} + \cdots  $$
where $\,c = a_2/e^{a_0}.\,$ For simplicity assume that
$\,a_0=0, a_2=1.\,$ The solution of equation $(4)$ is
$$ f(x) = \sec\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2 =
 1\frac{x^2}{2!} +4\frac{x^4}{4!} +34\frac{x^6}{6!} + \cdots  $$
where the coefficients are [OEIS sequence A002105](https://oeis.org/A002105).

Comment: very clever approach !

Comment: +1 Shouldn't equation (2) be $a_n:=cf(n)$?

Comment: @EliBartlett Oops! Thanks for that correction.

Answer (score 1):

Being a combination of product and sum, it looks difficult
that there might be a closed form.

The best I can suggest is to make the substitution

$$
f(n) = 2^{g(n)} 
$$
I am using $2$ as a base because $2^n$ has a simple difference.

Then
$$
\eqalign{
  & f(n + 1) - f(n) = 2^{g(n + 1)}  - 2^{g(n)}  = 2^{g(n)} \left( {2^{g(n + 1) - g(n)}  - 1} \right)  \cr 
  & 2^{g(n)} \left( {2^{g(n + 1) - g(n)}  - 1} \right) = c2^{g(n)} \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {2^{g(k)} }   \cr 
  & 2^{g(n + 1) - g(n)}  = 1 + c\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {2^{g(k)} }   \cr 
  & 2^{g(n + 2) - g(n + 1)}  - 2^{g(n + 1) - g(n)}  = c2^{g(n + 1)}   \cr 
  & 2^{g(n + 2) - 2g(n + 1)}  - 2^{ - g(n)}  = c  \cr 
  & \left( {2^{g(n + 2) - 2g(n + 1) + g(n)}  - 1} \right)2^{ - g(n)}  = c  \cr 
  & 2^{\Delta ^2 g(n)}  = 1 + c2^{g(n)}   \cr 
  & 2^{\Delta ^2 g(n)}  = 1 + 2^{\ln c + g(n)}   \cr 
  &  \approx \Delta ^2 g(n) + g(n) = \ln c\quad \left| {\;1 <  < 2^{g(n)} } \right. \cr} 
$$

So the asymptotics is clear.